# Django CSRF verification failed. Webhook payment system

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, webhooks, mollie

I'm trying to implement a webhook for my payment system. I have a path to my webhook view, which is a simple definition where the provided id is printed.

The usage is like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/mollie-webhook/?id=ExampleId
```

Path

```
# mollie webhook
path('api/mollie-webhook/', mollie_webhook, name='mollie_webhook'),
```

View

```
def mollie_webhook(request):
    id = request.POST['id']
    print(id)
    return JsonResponse(data={"response": "Success!"})
```

I'm getting the following error

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Comment: Mark the view as csrf_exempt https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt?

Comment: @IainShelvington Works like a charm. Thanks! You can create an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator to mark the view as exempt from CSRF checks

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def mollie_webhook(request):
    id = request.POST['id']
    print(id)
    return JsonResponse(data={"response": "Success!"})
```